# Why Instagram doesn't allows access to email_id?

Tags: android, email, instagram, instagram-api

I would like to featuring users to login with Instagram besides with facebook & twitter in my app. Unlike fb & twitter, Instagram is not giving `email_id` field that seems embarrassing. Is there any security concern that only affect Instagram by providing `email_id` or any hacking guide to acquire `email_id` from team Instagram. It's **vital** **:(**   ?

Comment: Instagram is facebook's subsidiary.

Comment: This isn't the kind of answer I love to hear **#Shek :)**

Comment: I am sorry, what I meant was, Instagram is linked with facebook, As far as I understand facebook verifies login on Instagram, so when you provide a feature to logon using Instagram id you're basically using facebook to login.

Comment: For example, If you want your user to use their youtube account to login, you are basically asking them to login with their google account.

Comment: @Shek Instagram has a separate email value from Facebook. While initially they copy over the information from Facebook, they keep track of those things themselves too. It is a reasonable request to ask for their email on Instagram. #Stella Instagram does not provide access to user email.